# Cloud Functions V2 won't return a response after 600s even with timeout set to 3600s

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

V2 Cloud functions refuse to return a response after 10min even with a timeout of 60min. I had a function that runs for ~15min, then I setup the script below to figure out at what time responses stop:

```
import functions_framework
import time

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    sleep_time = int(request.args["sleep"])

    print("Starting sleep: ", sleep_time)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    print("Finished sleeping: ", sleep_time)

    return f"{sleep_time}"
```

It takes in an integer and sleeps for that number of seconds. Then returns the integer to show the function worked for that long.

So I setup a test and found that at exactly 600 seconds the function won't return a response
[image: Endpoint responses on my computer]

But weirdly enough the Cloud Function logs show that the 600 second function worked properly and should've returned a response.

[image: Google Cloud Function logs for the function above]

Does anyone know how to fix this? The timeout for this function was set to 3600s (1h) so that shouldn't be the problem. There also is never any timeout error

Comment: How do you invoke your Cloud FUnctions?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

Just with a simple HTTP GET request using the "requests" library 

Here's the code if you'd like to try, <trigger-url> is obviously the URL for the cloud function

https://pastebin.com/CLuUCHW5